# Flutter Unity Android Export Failed due to build.gradle file not found

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, flutter-dependencies

I was following the Unity - Flutter Integration Tutorial . I followed the steps given [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget). But when I click on the Export android option it shows the error below .

[image]

I am really confused what is happening here as I followed the steps in the tutorial and in the video the export is being stored in a android folder in the flutter project but here in my case its creating the android folder in a complete random location.

I do I solve this problem .

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for the Android folder inside your Flutter project directory, if you copy the whole Unity project to the Flutter directory, it is going to be able to find the android/build.gradle file.